# Adding an index in mysql workbench corrupted the table?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Step-by-step:

Right clicked on tbl > Table Inspector > Clicked "Columns" tab > Right click > Create Index >

[image]

In that section I left the following defaults:

[image]

- Algo: Default
- Locking: Default (allow as much concurrency as possible)

It gave a timeout error

I then tried to run a simple "SELECT * ", but it's timing out every time now.

I didn't think that adding an index can corrupt a table so I didn't do a backup and now in a bit of a panic mode... Is there anything that can be done to reverse this?

When doing the `show full processlist` I see the following:

[image]

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 'Waiting for table metadata lock' | 'CREATE INDEX `idx_all_mls_2_Centris_No` ON `mcgillim_matrix`.`all_mls_2` (Centris_No) COMMENT '''' ALGORITHM DEFAULT LOCK DEFAULT' |

Comment: can you try to run `show full processlist;` first if table is lock or not.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Hi Rohit, thank you for the comment, I updated the question

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA weird, it's not adding the image to the question.. but I'm not sure if the table is locked. I see waiting for table metadatalock

Comment: clearly visible, your table is in lock state with query like **select distinct t1.broker_name**.  First, let it complete or kill then you'll find progress in index creation.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA do you know how I can kill it? I waited more than 10 minutes, but it didn't complete

Comment: you will find id in information_schema.processlist corresponding to this SQL then run `kill ID;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234677/discussion-between-rohit-khurana-and-robert-sinclair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the processlist, it's clearly visible your **index creation** is waiting for metlock which means your table is already locked by another query which is like **select distinct t1.broker_name** and running from 3460 seconds.

You have two options here.

- Let that SQL complete first. Then index will create.
- Another, Kill that Select SQL which will not harm your system and can run later.

To kill query, You can find **ID** in information_schema.processlist. then simply run the below query.

> kill ID;

Comment: can you recommend the best way to add an index to a tbl without it locking up like that?

Comment: if you are using InnoDB engine and MySQL version 5.7 then run online alter else you can explore pt-online-schema-change or ghost.